# Copy field to payload

Tags: elasticsearch

When using suggesters in Elastic, it is possible to give a payload when indexing a document. Each time the suggester will be used, its payload will be given with the suggestions.

I would like to add the value of the id field of a document to the payload. While it is easy to do so at index-time, I would want to handle it in the mapping, because I don't want to change the way I convert documents to JSON.

I tried the following:

```
POST test
{
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "id": {"type": "String", "copy_to": ["field1_suggest.payload"]},
                "field1" : { "type" : "string", "copy_to": ["field1_suggest"]},
                "field1_suggest":{"type": "completion", "payloads": true}
            }
        }
    }
}

POST test/type1/1
{
    "id": "payload",
    "field1": "my value"
}
```

This fails, since "payload" is not a real field of field_suggest:

> "error": "MapperParsingException[attempt to copy value to non-existing object [field1_suggest.payload]]", "status": 400

How can I automatically include fields in the payload? If it is not possible, I guess I will have to use mainstream queries to get suggestions for completion...

Comment: why don't you do it by this [Indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing)

Comment: Because I don't want to change the JSON I use at index time, it is not recommended with my use case. I am specifically looking for a solution that fills the payloads in a transparent way for the document indexing.